# OCaml Function that takes in functions

Tags: ocaml

I need to write a `pipe` function in OCaml such  that `pipe [f1;...;fn]` (where `f1`,...,`fn` are functions!) returns a function `f` such that for any x, `f x` computes `fn(...(f2(f1 x)))`.

I need to write it using `List.fold_left` and need to fill in the parameter of the function

```
let pipe fs =
   let f a x = "fill in this part" in
   let base = fun x ->x in
   List.fold_left f base fs;;
```

I already filled in the base. If the first parameter to pipe is an empty list, it returns the second parameter. Ex: pipe [] 3 = 3.
i know for the let f a x part I want to perform function x of the accumulated functions a.
I'm just not sure how to write that.  I wrote let f a x = x a but that gave me an error when i tested 
pipe [(fun x -> x+x); (fun x -> x + 3)] 3

it should run x+x on 3 then run x+3 on the result and give me 9 but it gave it a type error when i tried to use let f a x = x a 
for the fill in part

```
# let _ = pipe [(fun x -> x+x); (fun x -> x + 3)] 3;;
File "", line 1, characters 24-25:

Error: This expression has type 'a -> 'a
       but an expression was expected of type int
```

What is the correct format to create a function that takes in 2 functions and runs them on each other. Ex: make a function that takes in functions a and b and runs b on the result of a.

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, the answer to your last question looks like this: `let f a b x = b (a x)`.

Comment: yes except im not allowed to change the left side so i cant have the b in there left side needs to be let f a x where a is the accumulator of functions and x is the next function that is popped off the list. so for example with       let _ = pipe [(fun x -> x+x); (fun x -> x + 3)] 3    the base function would be fun x -> x which is the first one stored in a.  It then needs to pop off the fun x-> x+x and store that function running on the base one in the accumulator.  Then it pops the last one, does the same thing and its done.  im assuming thats how its meant to work.

Comment: so for that example it would be like call fun x -> x+ 3 on the result of fun x->x+x which is called on the result of  fun x ->x which is called on 3. so it should give you 9

Comment: not exactly sure what you mean by this

Comment: I worked through your exercise, so I can give a hint. Your function `f` has to return a function. So it should return something that looks like this: `fun z -> ...`. You need to figure out what the returned function should be doing with its argument `z`.

Comment: gotcha this worked fun z-> x(a(z)) just needed to add a variable the function is called on'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `base` is a function like this `fun x -> ...`.

Similarly, your function `f` needs to return a function, so assume it returns something that looks like this:

```
fun z -> ...
```

You have to figure out what this function should be doing with its argument `z`.

Answer (score 1):

To evaluate `(fold_left g init fs) x`:

- when `fs` is empty, `(fold_left g init fs) x = init x`. In your case, you want it to be `x`.
- when `fs = fs' @ [fn]`: according to what you would like to be true, the expression should evaluate to
  `fn (fold_left g init fs' x)` but using the definition of `fold_left` it evaluates also to `(g (fold_left g init fs') fn) x`.

Hence if the following equations are true:

- `init x = x`
- `(g k f) x = f (k x)`

the problem is solved. Hence, let us define `init = fun x -> x` and
`g k f = fun x -> f (k x)`.

Comment: It was difficult, congratulations.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out just needed that z in there for a and x to call